# Sharepoint Online Calculated Field (Date)

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to create an IF statement in a calculated field that will display different dates depending on what a certain column is, Here is what I have and it "should" work but nothing is being calculated

```
=IF(Category="Appointment",SUM(Date+.5/24,IF(Category="Lunch",SUM(Date+2/24,""))))
```

Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify that a bit...

```
=Date + IF( Category="Appointment", 0.5/24, 2/24 )
```

or

```
=Date + IF( Category="Appointment", 0.5, 2 ) / 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out and here is the way to write it:

`=SUM(IF(Category="Appointment",0.5/24,2/24),Date)`

Just in case someone has a similar issue please refer this answer.